# Getting errors in the "graph" code using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I've copied a code snippet from http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tkz-berge/ in order to see if I get it to run smoothly. I can not. Below is the snippet I've used:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,%
            petri,%
            topaths}%
\usepackage{tkz-berge}
\usepackage[position=top]{subfig}
\begin{document}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,transform shape]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[node distance = 4cm,%
                      bend angle    = 45,%
                      fill          = gray!30]
\Vertex(P)
\NOEA{P}(B)
\SOEA{P}(M)
\NOEA{B}(D)
\SOEA{B}(C)
\SOEA{C}(L)
\tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[pre and post]
\Edge[label=$4$](P)(M)
\Edge[label=$9$](C)(M)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Along with some additional edges and initializations of vertices which I omitted in this snippet. LaTeX however says that

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\in@ #1#2->\begingroup \def \in@@ 
                                  ##1#1{}\toks@ \expandafter {\in@@ #2{}{}#1...
```

and highlights the code snippet `\Edge[label=$4$](P)(M)`. The error is so confusing... and since I copied it from a site which has evidently run it, what can the issue be then?

Could somebody help me this?

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax in the code from TeXample is wrong (perhaps there was a change in the syntax sometime after the code was posted there and it has not been updated?). In any case, `\Vertex` has to be used with braces, as in `\Vertex{P}` and `\NOEA` (and similar) receives a first argument inside parentheses and the second one inside braces, as in `\NOEA(P){B}`. Additionally, the lines

```
\tikzstyle{every node}=[node distance = 4cm,%
                      bend angle    = 45,%
                      fill          = gray!30]
```

don't seem to be taken into account; I replaced them with

```
\SetGraphUnit{4}
\tikzset{
  VertexStyle/.append style={
    bend angle    = 45,%
    fill          = gray!30
  }  
}
```

You can check the proper syntax in the documentation for `tkz-graph`.

Here's a corrected reduced version of your code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz,fullpage}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,petri,topaths}%
\usepackage{tkz-berge}

\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75,transform shape]
\SetGraphUnit{4}
\tikzset{
  VertexStyle/.append style={
    bend angle    = 45,%
    fill          = gray!30
  }  
}
\Vertex{P}
\NOEA(P){B}
\SOEA(P){M}
\NOEA(B){D}
\SOEA(B){C}
\SOEA(C){L}
\tikzstyle{EdgeStyle}=[pre and post]
\Edge[label=$4$](P)(M)
\Edge[label=$9$](C)(M)
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]